# MapQuest - OSM Continent styling

Tags: openlayers, tiles, styling, openstreetmap, mapquest

I am trying to customize style of MapQuest but I don't know how ,

I read articles and developers documentation for both MapQuest

I also tried to make a custom tiles but the problem I don't have a web server to serve the new tiles

I just want to change continents colors

Can you provide me any articles,tutorial or code

I know I should add code I tried , but I tried a lot of things and I am pretty new to OSM & MapQuest so helping me with my code will exhaust you more than provide me on of the things I asked before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Mapnik style files](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/map/style) are available to users who wish to generate and host their own tiles based on customized MapQuest-OSM styling, but unfortunately there are no calls that can be made to customize colors on the OSM tiles that are hosted by MapQuest.

You can also provide feedback and suggest styling changes on the [MapQuest Developer Network Forums](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/info/forums).  The forums are also a great place to ask questions about the [Open MapQuest APIs and Web Services](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open) as well.